# Check if entity was already added to CrmServiceContext (prior to saving)

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I am using C# to read a .csv file and upload the contents to CRM. The file contains information on multiple entities that may need to be created/updated.
I want to use CrmServiceContext to do the changes, and call SaveChanges once at the end.

The problem arises when there are multiple lines referencing the same account (or any entity, but I'll use account for this example), which does not exist in the database yet.

My initial idea was to query the context AccountSet to see if an account with the given name exists, and if not, create the Account object and use AddObject to add it to the context. This however will cause multiple copies will be created, as using AddObject does not actually add the entity to the set until changes are saved.

I know I could just do SaveChanges after every new object or use IOrganizationService.Create instead, but that would make the upload take longer so I'd rather avoid it if possible. What would be the best way to check if an entity with a given attribute value is already set to be created?

Comment: Perhaps u can do with this with sqlbulkcopy feature for csv file import and submitting data u can check name already exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use the same context ? Actually it should add new entity to context even if transaction is not submitted and you can retrieve it before next adding . Do you  attach your entity after adding it to context ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/org-service/organizationservicecontext

Could you provide code that are used for adding new entity ?

Also you could check your new added entities with `GetAttachedEntities()` collection (all your not commited changes is added there)

```
var ents = Context.GetAttachedEntities()
                .Where(x => x.EntityState.HasValue && x.EntityState.Value == EntityState.Created).ToList();
```